# TypeError: Property xxx of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: knockout.js

I have problem with this Typeerror. I'm a novice and I wasn't able to find the solution of this problem.

TypeError: Property 'currentPage' of object [object Object] is not a function

The code is here: https://gist.github.com/Jirda/8852736

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line (line no. 14 in your code)

```
self.goNextPage = function() {
                self.load(self.currentPage() + 1, self.limit);
            }
```

you are trying to use `self.currentPage()` with `()`, i.e. , you are trying to invoke the `property` as a `function`, which is not allowed, hence the error.

just use:

```
self.goNextPage = function() {
                    self.load(self.currentPage + 1, self.limit);
                }
```

EDIT:

in `self.currentPage(data.currentPage)` also, you are using it with braces

Comment: I fix it but the error is reported here all the time self.currentPage(data.currentPage);

Comment: BTw. that fixed row reports the error too. Brackets doesn't matter.

Comment: you have used the braces in many places in the program. are you sure the error is not because of this ?

Comment: the problem was in the template - there I used a name without brackets...and when observable variable was changed, the error was thrown